# To display the value of MATLAB cell array elements

Tags: matlab

Consider

```
  New_string=mat2cell(X,20,[10,10]);
  celldisp(New_string)
  String_1=New_string(1)
  String_2=New_string(2)
```

Output

```
 String_1 = 

[20x10 char]


String_2 = 

[20x10 char]
```

I want to assign the value of `New_string(1)` and `New_string(2)` into `String_1` and `String_2` respectively, but when I run the above code all it displays is the dimension of `String_1` and `String_2`. How do I get it to display the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It assigned the cells just fine, but you want the *content* of the cells.  Use `{}` instead of `()` (i.e. `String_1=New_string{1};`).